# perl, parsing XML using XML::Simple

Tags: perl, xml-simple

I'm doing something wrong when parsing XML. 
Somehow I has to iterate two loops, where only one should be needed. What am I doing wrong here?

First the xml data:

```
<fishy>
  <fish displayName          = "Scalar"
        description          = "the first fish I bought."
   />
  <fish displayName          = "crystal red"
        description          = "not really a fish."
   />
</fishy>
```

Then my perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

#Read configuration
my $simple = XML::Simple->new();
my $data   = $simple->XMLin('test.xml');
print Dumper($data) . "\n";


my @fishes = $data->{fish};

#This is weird.. Why do we have nested arrays?
foreach my $fish (@fishes)
{
  foreach my $innerFish (@{$fish})
  {
    print ("\n" . $innerFish->{displayName} . " is " . $innerFish->{description});
  }
    print ("\n");
}
```

And finally the response (which is fine)

```
$VAR1 = {
          'fish' => [
                    {
                      'description' => 'the first fish I bought.',
                      'displayName' => 'Scalar'
                    },
                    {
                      'description' => 'not really a fish.',
                      'displayName' => 'crystal red'
                    }
                  ]
        };


Scalar is the first fish I bought.
crystal red is not really a fish.
```

Comment: what happens if you do without?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create an array with one element (a reference to an array) with

```
my @fishes = $data->{fish};
```

Then you iterate over the elements of that array with

```
foreach my $fish (@fishes)
```

That's just a really weird way of doing

```
my $fish = $data->{fish};
```

Let's use that, but rename `$fish` to `$fishes`, and `$innerFish` to `$fish`.

```
my $fishes = $data->{fish};
for my $fish (@$fishes) {
   print($fish->{displayName}, " is ", $fish->{description}, "\n");
}
```

Don't forget to use the `ForceArray => [qw( fish )]` option to make sure the code works when you only have a single fish.

Answer (score 0):

`my @fishes = @{$data->{fish}};`

Comment: ug, needless copy of an array. That's a complete waste.